Unable to add Alfresco Activiti Repository URL to internal Nexus Repository
We want to add Alfresco Activiti Repository URL https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public (that contains 8.1.0 version jars) to our internal Nexus Repository.

We tried to add a proxy Repository in Nexus as shown in above screenshot. But it's not working. The nexus version we are using is 2.13.0.
However, the same URL https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public
when added in our local mvn setting.xml file its downloading jars.
The problem with this approach is each developer has to add has to add this URL in settings.xml file locally for the jars to get downloaded.
